# Grab value from interval using jquery and options in form

Tags: jquery

I would like to grab the class value from the right option from selectbox

```
<select id="ammount">
<option value="">- Select -</option>
<option class="100" value="0">5,00</option>
<option class="200" value="5,01">10,00</option>
<option class="300" value="10,01">15,00</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {

        $('form').on('change', '#height', function(){
            var height  = $('#height').val(); // e.g. height  = "3,00";

            // HERE I NEED TO GRAB THE RIGHT OPTION FROM SELECT OPTIONS WHERE HEIGHT (e.g. 3,00) IS IN
            // THE INTERVAL BETWEEN VALUE (e.g. value="0") AND TEXT (e.g. 5,00)
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, if I have height that is 3,00 the right option would be the first:

```
<option class="100" value="0">5,00</option>
```

and I need to **grab the value of the class (e.g. 100 or 200 or 300 etc. ) and store it in a new variable. e.g. price**

So, I need somehow build the intervals where the first value would be the value from value="xxxx" and the second the text() value in between option tags.

Comment: what kind of input is #height ? what do you mean by "grab option" ? you want to select them or just get the value ?

Comment: @johnSmith it's from standard input box that is typed by a user. It will be a value like 3,00 or 3 or 4,50 etc. and then I need to find the right option that this number fits in the interval (formed from value="" and text between option tags.

Comment: note that "," in "3,5" must be a "." to let that work

Comment: @johnSmith well thanks that's another problem I have to solve ;). I was thinking that it could be done by finding only the bigger `value=""` and the first bigger occurence minus 1 is the right interval. But the intervals could be inconsistent so I don;t think this is the right approach and they can be in other than asc/desc order. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, if I understand pattern properly

```
$('form').on('change', '#height', function(){
     var height  = valToNum($(this).val()); // e.g. height  = "3,00";
     var amtOpts=$('#ammount option:gt(0)');
     var selected= amtOpts.filter(function(){        
         return height > this.value && height <= ( $(this).next().val() || Infinity);
     }).prop('selected',true);

    $('#res').text(selected.attr('class'))

})

function valToNum(val){    
    return 1* $.trim(val).replace(/,/g,'.');    
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mLs7b/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Hmm, thanks but it is not working if I set the vlue to 11 it selects the first row instead of the last

Comment: works fine for me...using FF..what browser? try this one  http://jsfiddle.net/mLs7b/2/

Comment: For some reason this is breaking my code: `var height = valToNum($(this).val());`

Comment: so what error is thrown? If it works in fiddle, should work fine in your code

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, my values in selectbox are dnamically pulled from db, maybe that's the problem ;(

Comment: didnd't anwser about errors..check console. Also note i made values numeric. Copy output you have to jsfiddle and save

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem is that in my code I have `value="5,01"` and you are using `value="5"` therefore it's throwing bad values. Any Idea how to make it work with decimal numbers and accepting comma from the value as a decimal separator in the code?

Comment: not sure why you would want non numeric values...but can pass them through `valToNum` first. Really doesn't make sense, when using numbers is proper approach

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mLs7b/1/ try to change 5 to 5,01 and 10 to 10,01 and it will stop working.

Comment: why not just replace `,` with decimal point??...otherwise use `valToNum()` to convert